# Verify Login Details to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on my own CMS.

It seems like it doesn't accept my login details for some reason... The codes are:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    // display index
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)){
            $error = 'Please enter all of the fields!';
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
             // user entered correct
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
            //user entered false
                $error = "Incorrect details!";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

            <br /><br />

            <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>

            <small style="color:#aa0000;">
            <?php echo $error; ?>
            <br /><br />
            </small>

            <?php } ?>

            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
}

?>
```

And the connection are:

```
> <?php
> 
> try { $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website', 'root',
> '');  } catch (PDOException $se) {    exit('Database error.'); }
> 
> 
> ?>
```

Every time i try to login with the correct details it just says ''Incorrect Details''

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to do: `$num = $query->rowCount(); var_dump($num);` It's a good start to check what the result you're comparing with actually is :) And you shouldn't use MD5, please consider changing to Bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: For a **better password encryption**, have a look at [PHPs `hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function. To check which hashing algorithms are available on your php install, use [`hash_algos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php).

Comment: Off topic, but you are using MD5 for hashing a password in this code snippet. It is recommended to not use MD5 for this purpose anymore. Use a stronger hash algorithm, or if you're using PHP 5.5 use `password_hash` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @Bjoern he really should be using 2ROT13

Comment: @Jodelina Don't let Cole fool you - listen to Bjoern, and check these two security.SE questions: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5605/3272 and http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4781/3272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the query returned a result. However the way you do it is not for SELECT queries. It's used for e.g. deletes.

### Try this instead:

```
<?php
if ($res = $conn->query($sql))
{
    if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0)
    {
        // user entered correct
    }
    else
    {
        //user entered false
    }
}
```

More information about this can be found in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1038).

**I want to add this quote from the manual:**

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
> number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
> PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
> predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
> be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.